# Copy data from sheet to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I wrote a function that copies data from one sheet to another
in the first sheet I have 3 columns of 3 different rules ( completeness, accuracy, validity ) but in the second sheet I want to collect these rules in a single column and put the type of each rule in front (see photo, the SOURCE sheet is what I have and the COPY sheet is what I want to have)

Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHnMu.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XtPR.png)

```
Function columnLookup(Name As String, Line As Range) As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim Cell As Range

i = 0
For Each Cell In Line
    If Cell.Value = Name Then
       i = Cell.Column
    End If
 Next Cell
 columnLookup = i
 End Function

Sub CopyfromSource()

Dim k As Variant
Dim localworksheet, globalWorksheet As String
Dim currentLine, currentLine1 As Integer
Dim classeur As Workbook


Dim headerSource As Range
Dim headerCopy As Range

Dim attributSource, attributCopy As Integer


globalWorksheet = "Source"
localworksheet = "Copy"


Worksheets(globalWorksheet).Activate

Set headerSource = Worksheets(globalWorksheet).Range("A1", Worksheets(globalWorksheet).Range("A1").End(xlToRight))
Set headerCopy = Worksheets(localworksheet).Range("A1", Worksheets(localworksheet).Range("A1").End(xlToRight))

attributSource = columnLookup("Attribute", headerSource)
attributCopy = columnLookup("Attribute", headerCopy)

'Copy

currentLine1 = 2

For k = 2 To 10

    Worksheets(localworksheet).Cells(currentLine1, attributCopy).Value = Worksheets(globalWorksheet).Cells(k, attributSource).Value
    
    currentLine1 = currentLine1 + 1

Next k

Worksheets(localworksheet).Activate
ActiveSheet.Copy
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with PQ (Power Query). In order to see what did I do, paste the below code in the Advanced Editor of PQ. First of all, put your data in a Table (Insert>Table). In my example, named as Tabela1 (I work with Excel in PtBr language and so the steps on PQ are in Portuguese. But  don't care of it. Certainly will run).

```
let
    Fonte = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabela1"]}[Content],
    #"Tipo Alterado" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Fonte,{{"Attribute", type text}, {"Rule completeness", type text}, {"Rule Accuracy", type text}, {"Rule Validity", type text}}),
    #"Somente as Colunas Selecionadas Foram Transformadas em Linhas" = Table.Unpivot(#"Tipo Alterado", {"Rule completeness", "Rule Accuracy", "Rule Validity"}, "Atributo", "Valor"),
    #"Colunas Renomeadas" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Somente as Colunas Selecionadas Foram Transformadas em Linhas",{{"Atributo", "Rule Type"}, {"Valor", "Rule"}}),
    #"Valor Substituído" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Colunas Renomeadas","Rule ","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Rule Type"}),
    #"Colocar Cada Palavra Em Maiúscula" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Valor Substituído",{{"Rule Type", Text.Proper, type text}}),
    #"Colunas Reordenadas" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Colocar Cada Palavra Em Maiúscula",{"Attribute", "Rule", "Rule Type"})
in
    #"Colunas Reordenadas"
```